# How to solve the ODE : $y''' -2y'' + 2y' = 4\cos(x)\cos(3x) +6\sin(x)^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ODE: $$y'''  -2y'' + 2y' = 4\cos(x)\cos(3x) +6\sin(x)^2$$

I managed the find a solution to the homogeneous part, as it is pretty simple.
However I can't manage to find the private solution for the non-homogeneous.

I know to find the private solution when the right hand side is a quasi polynomial, but here it isn't and I can't bring it to the form of a quasi polynomial.

I'll appreciate some help.

Comment: Use trig identities to make the right-hand side a sum of simple sines and cosines rather than products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: 1) Show that $$4\cos(x)\cos(3x)+6\sin(x)^2=3-\cos(2x)+2\cos(4x)$$ and for the particular solution make the ansatz
$$y_p=a_1x+a_2\cos(2x)+a_3\cos(4x)+a_4\sin(2x)+a_5\sin(4x)$$

Comment: Thank your for your hint!

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I've been missing

Answer (score 3):

The auxiliary polynomial is $\lambda (\lambda^2-2\lambda+2)$ with roots $0,\,1\pm i$, so if $y=y_0$ is a solution so is $y=y_0+A+Be^x\cos x+Ce^x\sin x$. You should be able to obtain a choice for $y_0$ from the fact that the ODE's right-hand side is $3+\Re (2\exp 4ix-\exp 2ix)$.